# Need help updating PHP 5.2 to 5.3 (on Debian Lenny)

Tags: php, debian, apt, php5

I need to update 5.2 to 5.3 in one of our servers urgently. My unix skills are limited so please be as specific as possible.

Is there any way to do this easily with `apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: I don't even say what Debian version you are using.

Comment: But I guess it must be Debian 5 (Lenny). In that case: No, there is no easy way to just upgrade PHP with apt.

Comment: Why not? There is an easy way. Upgrade from lenny to squeeze. Instructions are here: http://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html But you have to read it on your own.

Comment: @mailq: I consider a distribution upgrade something that is never easy and certainly shouldn't be done without proper planning and testing (or just because someone *urgently* needs a new PHP version). And even while Debian updates are working relatively well most of the time, there is still the potential for major problems.

Comment: The only easy way would be if PHP 5.3 where in lenny-backports, but it isn't.

Comment: @SvenW I'm with you. But merging packages from different releases is even more evil. Everybody who *urgently* works on a production server needs to be fired **immediately**.

Comment: Sorry guys. The Debian version is indeed Lenny. If it is not possible with apt-get, then please explain the easiest way...

Comment: @mailq it's not a production server, but I guess being a smartass on the internet is more important that trying to be helpful

Comment: I don't think he was really being a smartass. Trying to upgrade the package when it's not in the official repos is a little risky when it comes to support and dependencies. Apparently "Squeeze" has the version you're looking for in it, and it would be better supported. Shoehorning it in, if you're not Linux-savvy, is not without some potential issues.

Comment: And all the issues, risks and procedures are explained in my linked document. But you can see that this is not a procedure of 5 minutes. Which means *urgently* is a relative term and needs thorough thoughts and a fixed time line (of some days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions available that might work at http://www.debiantutorials.com/how-to-install-upgrade-to-php-5-3-on-debian-lenny/

But you need to first have working backups in place. Best to test this on another install somewhere else to make sure there aren't any "gotchas", and if this is a production server and something goes wrong,...

Your support documentation is up to date, yes?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 Packages can be sourced from:

- for Debian 6.0 Squeeze : on the main Dotdeb repository
- for Debian 5.0 “Lenny” : on php53.dotdeb.org

Follow the instructions using aptitude or plain old apt